# Python Unittest woes: not all argument converted during string formatting

Tags: python, python-unittest

When running unittest, I receive a "not all arguments converted during string formatting." When running the code directly, everything works fine; it's only running Unittest that's a problem. When I run the same exact command `map.add_node('a','b','c','d')` directly there is no problem

Main program:

```
    def add_node(self, *args):
      main_node = args[0]
      connected_nodes = args[1:]
      if main_node in self.graph_dict:
        main_node = str(main_node) #getting desperate here
        print('%s in graph already. Updating...\n' % main_node) #** problem is here
      else:
        print('%s added.\n' % main_node)
      self.graph_dict.update({main_node: connected_nodes})
      return
```

Unittest:

````
  def test_add_node(self):
       graph = main.Graph()
       nodes = ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
       graph.add_node(nodes)
       self.assertEqual(True,False)```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not comparing apples to apples.

You describe two ways of calling `add_node()` and one of them is wrong.

Perhaps you meant:

```
graph.add_node(*nodes)
```

Comment: Thanks. Just learned *args and didn't realize I had to * a variable when passed in.